# paralyse tree creation in java

Tags: java, multithreading, tree

I need to create a tree with huge number of nodes. Each node may have pretty big amount of children, and I want to speed up tree creation.

My tree structure is:

```
public class Node {
   int value; 
   int deep;
   List<Node> children;

   public Node(int value, int deep) {
      this.value = value;
      this.deep = deep;
   }

   public List<Node> getChildren() {
      return children;
   }
}
```

So I want to create a tree where each node has 49 children and there are 10 000 000 elements in total in whole tree

I decided not to use recursion in order to use memory more efficiently, and my trivial single-threaded algorithm looks the following:

```
public Node buildTree() {
   Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
   Node root = new Node(...);
   stack.push(root);

   while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      Node current = stack.pop();
      current.getChildren().addAll(createNodes(current));
      stack.addAll(current.getChildren());
   }

   return root;
}

public List<Node> createNodes(Node node) {
   if (node.deep > 5) { 
      return Collections.emptyList(); 
   } else {
      // creates and returns list of 49 elements
   }
}
```

I wanted to speed up tree creation and paralyse nodes creation, since creation is independent for each branch. I came up with the following solution:

```
public Node buildTree() {
   LinkedBlockingDeque<Node> stack = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
   ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   Condition workerFinishedCondition = lock.newCondition();
   ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

   Node root = new Node(...);
   stack.push(root);
   AtomicInteger numberOfRunningTasks = new AtomicInteger(0);

   // while running tasks left and elements in stack left 
   while (numberOfRunningTasks.get() != 0 || !stack.isEmpty()) {
      Node current = getElementFromStack(stack, lock, workerFinishedCondition);

      if (current != null) {   
         pool.submit(() -> createElementTask());
         numberOfRunningTasks.incrementAndGet()          
      } 
      // if (current == null) we check are there any working thread left, or maybe all 
      // threads finished working and no more elements will be produced in stack
   }
}

@Nullable
public Node getElementFromStack(BlockingQueue<Node> stack, Lock lock, Condition workerFinishedCondition) {
   executeInLock(lock, ()-> {
      Node element = stack.poll();
      if (element == null) {  
         workerFinishedCondition.awaitUninterruptibly();   // wait for new elements to appear in stack
      } 
      return element;
   });
}

public void createElementTask(Node node, AtomicInteger numberOfRunningTasks, Stack stack, Lock lock, Condition workerFinishedCondition) {
   node.getChildren().addAll(createAllNextStepsNodesFixed(node));
   stack.addAll(node.getChildren());
   numberOfRunningTasks.decrementAndGet();

   executeInLock(lock, () -> {
      workerFinishedCondition.signalAll();    // notify that new elements appeared in stack
      return Void.TYPE;
   });
}

public <T> T executeInLock(Lock lock, Supplier<T> supplier) {
   lock.lock();
   try {
      return supplier.get();
   } finally {
      lock.unlock();
   }
}
```

But I found out that concurrent solution works even slower! 
With *single thread solution* it took to create 10 013 305 elements: *23 seconds*, but with concurrent solution it took *31 seconds*

So I think I can get why concurrent solution works slower, but how can I make it faster?

### Update 1: Optimized code not to create so much workers

Pseudo code

```
Node buildTree() {
   Node root = createRoot(); 
   createChilden(root);

   forEach child: root {
     ForkJoinPool.submit(createChilden((child))  
   }
}
```

So I create separate thread for only first level children. Number of first level child is 57 => 57 tasks are submitted to ForkJoinPool. Number of created nodes for each such child is 178 809 => 178 809 nodes to create for each thread.

Moreover I've removed synchronization. 
**My total execution time is approximately the same as single threaded.**

The same with java code:

```
public Node buildTree() {
   ForkJoinPool pool = new(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

   Node root = new Node(...);
   root.getChildren().addAll(createNodes(root));

   Collection<Callable<Object>> collection = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Node child : root.getChildren()) {
      collection.add(() -> {
         addChildren(child);
         return Void.TYPE;
      });
   }
   pool.invokeAll(collection);

   return root;
}
```

Comment: creation of a node is too a small task. Overhead for task creation and synchronization is too large. Think how to make independent task do more job - for example, create at once 2 layers of the tree, containing 1+49+49*49 = 2452 nodes. You will need 10000000/2452= about 4000 tasks, so that the level of parallelism is still high, much greater than the number of available processors.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Please see my update